# Drupal CKEditor 5 - customize toolbar when focus on image caption

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

Pretty simple question - but I can't seem to find the answer in the documentation.

The image caption is documented on this page:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/images-captions.html

When you highlight/focus the caption, then the main toolbar will disable some of the buttons. For instance table, media etc. will become disabled until you "un-focus" the caption field.

I would like to disable the **B** and *I* buttons as well when the user highlight/focus the caption field. Where is this done? Doens't appear to be part of any configuration through the administration.

Thanks a lot.

Jan Engelhardt